# Merging with pandas : left_on with a date and right_on with the oldest time range having this date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Let's take these two sample dataframes :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A','A','B','C'], 'Date':["2020-03-01","2021-04-21","2020-12-10","2017-01-01"]})

  Id        Date
0  A  2020-03-01
1  A  2021-04-21
2  B  2020-12-10
3  C  2017-01-01

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A','A','B'], 'Start':["2020-01-01","2020-02-21","2019-12-10"],
                 'End':["2021-01-01","2021-02-21","2021-12-10"], "Value":[1,2,3]})

  Id       Start         End  Value
0  A  2020-01-01  2021-01-01      1
1  A  2020-02-21  2021-02-21      2
2  B  2019-12-10  2021-12-10      3
```

I would like to add a Value column to df1. The corresponding value can be found in df2, with same Id and if the Date (in df1) is between Start and End (in df2). If several possibilities, I want to take the Value with oldest Start date.

I currently do that with a for loop but it is very slow with my real big dataframe and I have the intuition that we could do that thanks to a left join, but I can't figure out how. Would you please have an idea ?

Expected output :

```
  Id        Date  Valeur
0  A  2020-03-01     1.0
1  A  2021-04-21     NaN
2  B  2020-12-10     3.0
3  C  2017-01-01     NaN
```

Comment: pd.merge_asof https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof

Comment: @ifly6 - That only works if "Id" is numeric

Comment: `ID` is a `by` variable, not an `on` variable. There isn't any requirement that it be numeric. The `Date` column needs to be a continuous variable, but dates are supported.

Comment: @ifly6: I'd be genuinely curious to see a working example with OP's data

Comment: @mozway I took a second look at the question and my initial judgement was wrong: the OP is seeking an oldest-match (of those which fall in the date range) rather than a latest one. Regardless, it also would not be a single-line process: an as-of merge would require imputing NA where the match date exceeds the end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.merge()` + `.between()` + `drop_duplicates()`:

```
# Sort if not already in `Id`, `Start` order
#df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['Id', 'Start'])

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Id')
df3_filtered = df3.loc[df3['Date'].between(df3['Start'], df3['End'])]

df4 = df3_filtered.drop_duplicates(['Id', 'Date'], keep='first')

df_out = df1.merge(df4[['Id', 'Date', 'Value']], how='left')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  Id        Date  Value
0  A  2020-03-01    1.0
1  A  2021-04-21    NaN
2  B  2020-12-10    3.0
3  C  2017-01-01    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered to a [similar (although a bit different) question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311480/16343464).

Let's [make sure that dates are datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and sort df2 by Start:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start'])
df2['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['End'])
df2.sort_values(by='Start', inplace=True)
```

Make df2's index an [IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html):

```
df2.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['Start'], df2['End'],closed='both')
```

Craft a custom function and apply on rows:

```
def get_date(s):
    try:
        d = df2.loc[s['Date']]
        return d[d['Id'] == s['Id']].iloc[0]['Value']
    except KeyError:
        pass

df1['Value'] = df1.apply(get_date, axis=1)
```

output:

```
  Id       Date  Value
0  A 2020-03-01    1.0
1  A 2021-04-21    NaN
2  B 2020-12-10    3.0
3  C 2017-01-01    NaN
```